# Color Code Rows in a Data Grid Based on a Gradient in VB.Net Forms

Tags: vb.net, winforms, gradient, linear-gradients, lineargradientbrush

I have a grid containing rows flagged with different priorities. I want to color the high priority rows red, low ones blue, etc.

I'd like to set the shade based on a mathmatically calculated gradient rather than arbitrarily assigning colors to specific priorities.  How can I extract a single color from a single point along gradient?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like

VB.Net

```
Private Shared Function ColorGradientRedToBlue(ByVal index As Single) As Color
    If index < 0 OrElse index > 1.0R Then
        Throw New ArgumentException("index must be between 0 and 1")
    End If
    Return Color.FromArgb(CInt(((1.0R - index) * 255)), 0, CInt((index * 255)))
End Function
```

C#

```
static Color ColorGradientRedToBlue(float index)
{
    if (index < 0 || index > 1.0)
        throw new ArgumentException("index must be between 0 and 1");
    return Color.FromArgb((int)((1.0 - index) * 255), 0 ,(int)(index * 255));
}
```